# Cannot submit form from controller after ajax call [symfony]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have a view in which I need after a click to send a javascript variable to a controller which contains a form that I send to the database.
So after the click, I'm using ajax to call my controller and load the html on the same view like this:

```js
$(".month").click(function(){

            var click = $(this);

            var month = click.val();
            var year = $("#years").val();


            var url = Routing.generate('av_platform_formulaire');

            $.ajax(url,
                {
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {"month": month,
                          "year" : year},
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (data) {

                        $('#content').empty();
                        $('#content').append(data);

                    },
                    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){}
                });
});
```

So far there is no problem, my view containing the form is loading correctly and I receive the data I sent via the ajax request but when I fill my form and try to submit it, the page is refreshing and it's like nothing happens...

Here is my 2 controllers (the second is the problematic one):

```php
public function saisieAction(Request $request){

        $thisyear = date("Y");

        return $this->render('AvPlatformBundle:Platform:saisie.html.twig',
            array(
                'year' => $thisyear
            ));
}
```

```php
public function formulaireAction(Request $request){


        $user = $this->getUser();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        //$repository = $em->getRepository('AvPlatformBundle:NoteDeFrais');


        // Create the form
        $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder(FormType::class)
            ->add('ndf', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => NoteDeFraisType::class,
                'label' => false,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
            ))
            ->getForm();

        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){

            $month = $request->get('month');
            $year = $request->get('year');
            $sub_date = $month . '/' . $year;


        }

        if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
            // After debugging, the code inside the if is not executed
            $notesDeFrais = $form['ndf']->getData();


            foreach ($notesDeFrais as $ndf) {
                $ndf->setUser($user);
                $ndf->setMois($sub_date);
                $em->persist($ndf);
            }

            $em->flush();

        }

        return $this->render('AvPlatformBundle:Platform:formulaire.html.twig',
            array(
                'form' => $form->createView()
            ));
    }
```

My view containing the form:

```html
 <div id="ms_form">

        {{ form_start(form) }}


        <div id="bloc_saisie" class="fieldset">
            <fieldset>


                <div id="form_ndf" class="form_ndf" data-prototype="
                {% filter escape %}
                {{ include('AvPlatformBundle:Platform:prototype.html.twig', { 'form': form.ndf.vars.prototype }) }}
                {% endfilter %}">
                </div>

                <div class="buttons">
                    <button type="button" class="fas fa-plus" id="add_ndf"></button>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="next_button" >
                </div>


            </fieldset>
        </div>



        {{ form_row(form._token) }}
        {{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}


    </div>
```

Comment: The browser is still submitting the form the regular way; I assume it's `method` and `action` aren't set? Therefore submitting it will essentially refresh the page. Please add your form's HTML. In general, you'll want to handle `$(form).submit(...)` and `return false;` at the end.

Comment: The form is generated by symfony so I don't need to set method and action and to be precise: I'm not using ajax to submit the form. I'm adding my HTML view to the original post, thanks

Comment: And yeah the refresh is normal but the problem is that my form data is not sent to the database as expected

Comment: We seem to have communication issues. Are you saying you want to 1) make the ajax call, then 2) submit the form? (and please post rendered HTML from the browser, not server-side source)

Comment: you have 2 if one for the xhr request and one for the form submit and you are trying to pass the sub_Date from one to the other, this will not work because the xhr and the post request are 2 different instances of your controller

Comment: The ajax call is just to load the html page containing the form and pass my javascript variable. And I want to submit the form I loaded in a "normal way" without using ajax

Comment: Did you try to display the `{{ form_errors(form) }}`  to see if form is valid ?